# Installing node.js on debian. ./configure can't find openSSL while it is installed

Tags: node.js, openssl, debian

Because there isn't an up-to-date package of node to be found with apt-get, I downloaded the source with git and tried compiling it. However, it can't find the openssl libraries and installing without them will give problems downstream. (with other node userland modules requiring it). According to apt-get openssl is already up-to-date and it seems to be in the path as well, since typing 'openssl' executes it.
Anyone know what I am missing here?

Answer (score 4):

you should install libssl-dev

```
apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Answer (score 4):

I also needed to install libcurl4-openssl-dev on my machine :

```
apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to point `configure` at `openssl` for debian squeeze if you are building node from git: `--openssl-libpath=/usr/lib/ssl` - I actually wrote a [post about this recently](http://sekati.com/etc/install-nodejs-on-debian-squeeze).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me recently - no other steps required:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```